# How do I access a generated form from a website (java)

Tags: java, javascript, passwords

I'm a waiter at a restaurant. One of my responsibilities include assigning server sections and side work. Our company uses hotschedules.com to provide us with scheduling.

I have to log into the website and use the reports tab. There, a form is presented where i can select the date, output format, etc. Looking at the source code, The form uses javascript to determine my selections and generate a report. One of the ways the report can be generated is as an excel .xls file.

I have started looking through w3schools javascript tutorials but haven't found anything particularly useful for this specific issue. Further, hotschedules specifically will not provide an api for direct access to the report generator.

My question is:
Is there a way I can write my java program to access the reports form and pass javascript to it to retrieve the .xls file with pre-defined form options. Keeping in mind that I have to enter a username and password to access the website manually.

If anyone could offer any advice or links to resources that may help me, I would be appreciative. This is the only step in the program I'm writing I don't know how to do.

Thanks

Comment: greasemonkey and tampermonkey come to mind...

Comment: Do you want to fill the webform from your java programm and then download the excelfile?
You can post values to a weborfm sending a http post command. You would not need to pass javascript. You could also retrieve the xls file via http get but i assume this is a rocky road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not?
You have to inspect the HTML, resp. the `FORM`-Tag and its input-fields. In the `action`-part you see, where the data has to go. In the `method`-part you see how the data is transported: in the URL or in the body of the request.
Knowing that and how to encode your data, you would be able to write your App in any language you want.

A simpler option in my eyes would be the usage of e.g.[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) a headless browser, which could be used for automating your task.

And even simpler: [iMacros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMacros) is an extension for your browser to automate e.g. form filling.

So it's up to you how much time and effort you want to invest.